# Value of form field update in Django 1.6.6 after POST method

Tags: django-forms, updates

I am trying to update a form field after getting a form in the POST method. When I am trying to update the form I am getting following error

```
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.6.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'SmsPduForm' object does not support item assignment
```

My Form Code is

```
class SmsPduForm(forms.Form):
    """
    This class generates the SMS PDU form
    """
    pduType = (('1','SMS-SUBMIT'), ('2','SMS-DELIVER'))
    encoding = (('0','7 BIT'), ('8','UCS2'))
    Address = forms.CharField(max_length=20, min_length=5, required=True, label="Target Address",
                               initial="+917654321")

    SMSC = forms.CharField(max_length=13, min_length=5,required=True, label="SMSC Address",
                        initial="+91244414")

    PDUType = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=pduType, required=True,
                                label="PDU Type", initial=pduType[0])

    EncodingType = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=encoding, required=True, label="Encoding Type",
                                     initial=encoding[0])

    Text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'row':6, 'cols':50}),required=True, label="SMS Text",
                           initial="Hello", max_length=140)

    smsPDU = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'row':6, 'cols':50}),required=True, label="SMS PDU",
                           initial="Hello", max_length=140)

    #Meta class of the form
    class Meta:
        fields = ('Address', 'SMSC', 'PDUType',
                  'EncodingType', 'Text', 'smsPDU')
```

My view code is

```
def smsHandler(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        method=""
        #Do for post method else do for get method
        smsPduForm = SmsPduForm(request.POST)
        smsc = smsPduForm['SMSC'].value()
        address = smsPduForm['Address'].value()
        encodingType = smsPduForm['EncodingType'].value()
        pduType = smsPduForm['PDUType'].value()
        text = smsPduForm['Text'].value()
        smsPdu = smsPduForm['smsPDU'].value()
        print(smsc,address,encodingType,pduType,text,smsPdu)
        if "Encode" in request.POST:
            method = "encode"
            smsEncObj = SmsEncoder(encodingType, smsc, pduType, text, address )
            smsPdu = smsEncObj.generateSmsSubmitPdu()
            #SmsPduForm.clean_smsPDU()
            #Here I am updating the form
            smsPduForm['smsPDU'] = smsPdu
        elif "Decode" in request.POST:
            method = "decode"
        print("Action need to perform:",method)


        contextDic = {'forms':SmsPduForm}
        return render_to_response('telecom_utils/smsUtil.html',contextDic,context)
    else:
        contextDic = {'forms':SmsPduForm}
        return render_to_response('telecom_utils/smsUtil.html',contextDic,context)
```

How can i update the form ? Kindly look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the initial property of the field in a form to update the value .
Example :

```
def smsHandler(request):
    # --- your logic        
            #Here I am updating the form
            sms_form = smsPduForm()
            sms_form.fields["smsPDU"].initial = smsPdu
    # --- next logic
```

Comment: I used the logic as you mentioned but it is not updating the value of form field ( smsPDU )